# Ошибка при сборке проекта Maven в IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Сама ошибка:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project photohost: Compilation failure
[ERROR] ...modul/file/FileUpload.java:[18,35] static interface methods are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 8 or higher to enable static interface methods)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Ссылкаеться на это:

```
public interface FileUpload {


static String generateFileName **[ССЫЛАЕТЬСЯ НА ЭТО МЕСТО]**(){
    ***....***
    return fileName;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статические методы в интерфейсах введены только в Java 8. Вы компилируете стандартом более ранней версии.

Ошибки нужно читать - это полезно.

```
static interface methods are not supported in -source 1.5
(use -source 8 or higher to enable static interface methods)
```

Установите и используйте последнюю версию JDK. В compiler plugin версия указывается следующим образом:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Странно. Ставил везде только 1.8 но сработало только при записи в pom

Comment: Я плохо сформулировал. Дело не том какую версию вы установили, а в параметре `source`. Компилятору Java можно указать [использовать стандарт более ранней версии](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html). По умолчанию, `maven-compiler-plugin` не знает что за версия JDK у вас установлена, поэтому использует `source = 1.5`. Не знаю как в IDEA, например, но Eclipse сам определяет версию JDK Maven проекта через параметр `source`.